# mejorar rendimiento de codigo para textarea js

Tags: javascript, html, bucle-for, textarea

mi pregunta es bastante consiza, tengo una codigo para cambiar el tamaño de los textarea cuando alguien está escribiendo:

```
if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'textarea') {
    let contador = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < e.target.value.length; i++)
      e.target.value[i] == '\n' ? (contador += 1) : null;
    e.target.rows = contador + 1;
  }
```

La cosa es que me he dado cuenta que esto baja el rendimiento de esa parte de la aplicación, ya que estoy haciendo un recorrido cada vez que un usuario escribe, ahora, si una frase tiene 100 palabras, son 100 recorridos del for :CCCCC, lo cual no me parece muy malo, como podría mejorar este codigo?

edit:
Se me olvidó poner el evento que ejecuta esto:

```
document.querySelector('.ctn-toDoList').addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'textarea') {
    let contador = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < e.target.value.length; i++)
      e.target.value[i] == '\n' ? (contador += 1) : null;
    e.target.rows = contador + 1;
  }
});
```

Comment: ¿Cuál evento estás escuchando para aplicar esta función?¿Quién la invoca?

Comment: @FranAcuna maaan JAJAJAJ, se me olvidó ponerlo, espere y edito la publi.

Comment: ¿Y si haces que incremente el contador cada vez que el usuario presiona `enter` y el `textarea` esta activo? Porque al final de cuentas estás recorriendo todo el `textarea` para ver si incrementas en 1 el contador porque alguién ingreso un nuevo carácter de tipo `newline`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

he cogido un poco de ambas respuestas, por lo cual al final quedó de la siguiente manera:

```
document.querySelector('.ctn-toDoList').addEventListener("input", (e)=>{
  if (e.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'textarea') {
    e.target.style.height = 'auto';
    e.target.style.height = `${e.target.scrollHeight}px`;
  }
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo, según tu código, que intentas hacer una nueva línea cada que presionas enter.

Esta es una opción en la que en lugar de editar las filas de tu `textarea` vas a incrementar o decrecer el tamaño del recuadro (`height`). Puedes agregar además un `overflow-y: hidden` para ocultar la barra de scroll.

```js
function textareaNewSize(textarea) {
   textarea.style.height = "0px";
   textarea.style.height = textarea.scrollHeight + "px";
}
```

```css
textarea {
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Tu textarea</h1>
<textarea class="ctn-toDoList" onkeyup="textareaNewSize(this);"></textarea>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Una opción es crear una variable para obtener el *textarea* y asignar el atributo de altura desde que se carga la página y el evento *onInput* para que se apliquen los cambios al escribir o cortar y pegar.

```js
// Obtener el elemento
let textarea = document.querySelector('.ctn-toDoList');
// Cambiar atributos de estilo, asignando altura de acuerdo a contenido inicial
textarea.setAttribute('style', 'height: ' + (textarea.scrollHeight) + 'px; overflow-y:hidden;');
// Asignar evento onInput
textarea.addEventListener("input", textareaOnInput, false);

function textareaOnInput(e) {
  // Es necesario usar primero "auto" y, después, la altura de scroll
  e.target.style.height = 'auto';
  e.target.style.height = (e.target.scrollHeight) + 'px';
}
```

```html
<textarea class="ctn-toDoList">Escribe para ver cómo funciona, puedes comenzar con un texto largo y se va a adaptar.</textarea>
```

Adaptado de [esta respuesta en SO en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25621277/2412893)